# Rotate a Unit Vector by a Given Quaternion

Tags: java, opengl, math, rotation, quaternions

I am attempting to calculate the unit vector which points out of my opengl camera.  Given a rotation quaternion (w,x,y,z), how would I calculate the rotation of a unit vector around that quaternion?

In this case, the unit vector can be limited to (0,0,-1).

**EDIT: Final solution**

For rotation of (0,0,1):

```
vec.x=2*x*z - 2*y*w;
vec.y=2*y*z + 2*x*w;
vec.z=1 - 2*x*x - 2*y*y;
```

Note that the matrix needs to be transposed for use with OpenGL.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation ?

Comment: I've been reading through miles of text, trying to find an efficient solution.  If I find it before I get an answer here, I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the quaternion to a 3x3 rotation matrix and apply this rotation to your vector.

For a unit `(w, x, y, z)` quaternion, this matrix is:

```
      ( 1 - 2 * ( y * y + z * z )      2 * ( x * y - z * w )      2 * (x * z + y * w ) )
  R = (     2 * ( x * y + z * w )  1 - 2 * ( x * x + z * z )      2 * (y * z - x * w ) )
      (     2 * ( x * z - y * w )      2 * ( y * z + x * w )  1 - 2 * (x * x + y * y ) )
```

If your vector has such a simple form as `(0, 0, -1)`, you will not need to compute all the 9 coefficients of the rotation matrix since the result of the matrix vector multiplication only uses some of the coefficients (the last column of `R`).

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think you may have swapped a `+` for a `-` in the entry in the north-east corner.

Comment: I've already coded this, but it's terribly inefficient.  The point is to find a solution which does not rely on matrices. (question changed accordingly, and +1 anyways)

Comment: @Builder_K So 9 multiplications and 4 additions (5 taking into account the `-1`) are terribly inefficient for what you want to achieve (again only the last column of `R` is needed)? How many times per frame do you need to compute this?

Comment: depending on exact case, multiple thousands of times.

Comment: Well, since the right answer has those multiplications, additions and subtractions in it, it won't matter whether you express it as a matrix, or express it some different way - those are the calculations you will have to do.  I really don't see how you could possibly improve on this.

Comment: Implementing chosen answer of: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28395/rotating-vector3-by-a-quaternion
I'll post if/when it's working.

Comment: Just realized you're right, that is the only real solution... hm...  I will still post when done.